# Laravel Excel: how to have all zeroes printed in a exported csv?

Tags: laravel-excel

I'm exporting to csv using Laravel Excel.

I'm creating the out value as

```
 'amount' => number_format(-$ai->final_invoice_amount, 2, ".", "")
```

But, for example for `204.00`, in the exported csv I got only `204`, without dot and leading zeroes.

> I know that it's a valid number for a computer; but our client has a strict parser and it *wants* a `204.00` value.

I tried, but not works, to add an explicit cast to string, but it's useless because number_format outputs a string in any case

```
 'amount' => (string)number_format(-$ai->final_invoice_amount, 2, ".", "")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel Excel's Events give you access to PHPSpreadSheet under the hood.

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/extending.html#events

With Events, you can apply the desired formatting to a cell or group of cells. It's easier to demonstrate than explain, so I have created a simple example.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Export;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeSheet;

class SampleExport implements FromCollection, WithEvents
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return collect([
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'amount_1' => 100,
                'amount_2' => 75.20,
                'amount_3' => -23.10,
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'amount_1' => -60,
                'amount_2' => 50.40,
                'amount_3' => 110,
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            BeforeSheet::class => function (BeforeSheet $event) {

                // format columns B-D to two decimal places
                $event->sheet
                    ->getDelegate()
                    ->getStyle('B:D')
                    ->getNumberFormat()
                    ->setFormatCode('0.00');

            },
        ];
    }
}
```

This is the resulting CSV as output to a file.

```
"1","100.00","75.20","-23.10"
"2","-60.00","50.40","110.00"
```

NOTE: The values being formatted MUST BE A NUMBER TYPE! Attempting to format strings will not work.